# Im executing multiple classes in selenium, but could not be able to find driver in another class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

[testng.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/375PZ.png)

[Base driver classs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNLWo.png)

Null pointer error is displayed for another class method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others using source code formatting in the question instead of images. Currently you are not asking any question.

Comment: Use `PageFactory.initElements(BaseClass.driver, <Your Class name>.class);` in method which throws null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Constructor in your UI class like this

```
public LoginPage(IOSDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
       this.driver = driver;
       PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
   }
```

And in every Test create a new Reference for your LoginPage object. Follow the below code reference.

```
public class TestClass {

 LoginPage lPage=null;
 @Test(priority=1) 
 public void test1() 
    {
        lPage=new LoginPage(driver);

        boolean check1=lPage.TestdoLoginWIthValues();

        Assert.assertTrue(check1==true);

    }
}
```